# CoreOS : when pulling large docker image of size greater than 4 GB

Tags: linux, docker, coreos, docker-registry, docker-image

```
docker pull myimagename
```

leads to:

```
/var/lib/docker/overlay/670c89b1815cc9e3e27441690e47042fc554e432472ed8507`4284a890db56da0/    : no space left on device
```

**`df -h`**:

```
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on     ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ devtmpfs        4.3G     0  4.3G   0% /dev           ║
║ tmpfs           4.4G     0  4.4G   0% /dev/shm       ║
║ tmpfs           4.4G   17M  4.3G   1% /run           ║
║ tmpfs           4.4G     0  4.4G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup ║
║ tmpfs           4.4G  3.0G  1.4G  70% /              ║
║ /dev/loop0      162M  162M     0 100% /usr           ║
║ tmpfs           4.4G  228K  4.4G   1% /tmp           ║
║ tmpfs           4.4G     0  4.4G   0% /media         ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝
```

I can understand that, this is a space issue. But does that mean I cannot work on docker images of big size (in this case its 4 GB). How do I handle this problem?

Solution already tried:

I am running CoreOS on virtualbox.I tried increasing the virtual disk image size (even to 75 GB) , but still getting the same error.

Comment: Did you resize the partitions too after increasing the size of the virtual disk?

Comment: But during CoreOs installation , it didn't request for any partition size ...I guess that size is not configurable during the installation process

Answer (score 0):

From the output of your `df -h command` it looks like you are running CoreOS Live ISO image. So entire OS is loaded in RAM from the ISO (CD) and that CoreOS is not installed on the disk.

See https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/installing-to-disk.html on how to install CoreOS onto the disk (in most basic version of the installation you can execute `coreos-install -d /dev/sda` and CoreOS will be installed on sda, deleting all the data on the disk).

See output of `df -h` on my CoreOS installation:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs         16G     0   16G   0% /dev
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs            16G  1.9M   16G   1% /run
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda9       901G  588G  276G  69% /
/dev/sda4       985M  390M  545M  42% /usr
/dev/sda1       128M   58M   70M  46% /boot
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /media
tmpfs            16G     0   16G   0% /tmp
/dev/sda6       108M   52K   99M   1% /usr/share/oem
/dev/md126p1    1.8T  591G  1.2T  34% /home
```

Notice that mounting points are read disks and not tmpfs as in your case.

**Installing and running CoreOS from disk will solve your problem.**

Edit:

*If you have already installed CoreOS, you might be booting OS from the CD (ISO) you used to do installtion from. You need to change boot order or to remove CD (ISO), so CoreOS is booted from the disk you have installed it on.*

Comment: But kindly note , i am running coreOS in virtualbox. I am using iso downloaded from https://coreos.com/os/docs/latest/booting-with-iso.html ..

Comment: Yes, and you can use that ISO to install CoreOS on virtual drive attached to the VM instance you have created. For more detials about virtual drive and virtualbox see: https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch05.html